# Simple Qlik Sense Section Access

Tags: security, qlikview, qliksense

I am attempting to use section access with Qlik Sense. I am testing against "ADMIN1", that is a *RootAdmin* in *Qlik Sense*, but also admin in the Windows server. I tried the following script in data load editor, I hit load data, quit then re-enter. Qlik says: "Access Denied".

```
Section Access; 

LOAD * Inline [
 ACCESS, USERID

 ADMIN, ADMIN1

];

Section Application;

LOAD * Inline[

 Customer, Age

1,1];
```

I replaced `ADMIN, ADMIN1` with `ADMIN, DOMAIN1\ADMIN1` but still "Access is Denied". Same when I try `ADMIN, *` or `ADMIN, '*'`.

How can I make this simple test work?

Thanks,

Amir.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone comes across this same issue, here's an example:

```
section access;
LOAD 
ACCESS, USERID, SECURITY;
SQL SELECT access AS ACCESS,
    'DOMAIN\'+UPPER(userName) AS USERID,
    SECURITY
FROM dbo.securityRules;

section application;
LOAD 
field1,
field2,
secureFieldID AS SECURITY;
```

The securityRules table "Access" column is either set as "ADMIN" or as "USER", the secureFieldID column either indicates an ID which corresponds to the resource we are granting access to (e.g. cost centre ID, section ID etc) or it can be "*" for ADMIN which means they can see everything which is defined in the table (all users access).

Everything in uppercase per the example or it will not work.

Comment: If you want to load tables that don't require security, I've found that you must load them in a separate sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed that in all Sense documentation, regarding Section Access, there is no "ADMIN" value in "ACCESS" column. When I've changed "ADMIN" to "USER" everything worked.

```
Section Access; 

LOAD * Inline [
 ACCESS, USERID
 USER, MYDOMAIN\ADMIN1
];

Section Application;

LOAD * Inline[
 Customer, Age
1,1];
```

Also make sure that the username is used with domain prefix and this domain is added as "User directory connector" in QMC.

Comment: Thanks Stefan!! I tried just USER but it still didn't work. 
Here is where I saw ADMIN: http://help.qlik.com/sense/en-us/online/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/Security/SectionsInTheScript.htm

Comment: Sorry just now saw your comment. Still having issues?

Comment: Yes unfortunately. Never made it for a simple test. Thanks Stefan.